# Is it possible to pass kernel parameters in the LILO boot prompt?

Tags: lilo

Is it possible to pass kernel parameters in the LILO boot prompt?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can: type the parameters after the entry. In your case, would be `Linux` + the parameters (e.g. `Linux root=/dev/sda1`).

To show:

[image: passing foo=bar to kernel]

gives

[image: foo=bar at /proc/cmdline]